# How to share video(not url) to weibo?

Tags: ios, video, share, weibo

Is there any way to share video to weibo ? I don't mean just share video url. When I use 'UIActivityViewController', it isn't shown on the sharing items. Does it not support in sharing video for weibo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation in the following page, weibo does not support shairing Video from third party platforms.

Check the link below

[WEIBO DOCUMENTATION](http://sinaweibosdk.github.io/weibo_ios_sdk/Classes/WBVideoObject.html)

[WEIBO GITHUB PAGE](https://github.com/sinaweibosdk/weibo_ios_sdk)

Hope this helps....